# Rspec shoulda AttributeDoesNotExistError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have a clients model that was attached to users and all spec tests were passing fine. Later I realized that the clients would not need to log in so I removed the association. I added `f_name` and `l_name` columns. When I run shoulda matcher `validates_presence_of` for the `f_name` column, I get the error...

`Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::AllowValueMatcher::AttributeDoesNotExistError:
The matcher attempted to set :f_name on the Client to nil, but that attribute does not exist.`

I am using the attribute in the app and it does exist. I am able to populate the database with a seed file along with using it in the app.

I have dropped the database and recreated it along with `db:test:prepare` thinking that maybe the test database's schema did not change.

Why would I be having this problem?

rails_helper.rb

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'


Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
end
```

schema.rb

```rb
create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "f_name"
  t.string "m_name"
  t.string "l_name"
  ...
end
```

client_spec.rb

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Client, type: :model do
  it {should validate_presence_of(:f_name)}
  it {should validate_presence_of(:l_name)}
  ...
end
```

client.rb

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :f_name, :l_name
  ...
end
```

Comment: How did you remove the `association` ? Can you update your question with the `schema` which shows the `users` and `clients` definitions ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this.

```
RSpec.describe Client, type: :model do
  subject { Client.new(f_name: 'first_name', l_name: 'last_name') }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:f_name) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am not sure why it seemed to keep a transient. I ended up getting it to work by dropping the database then removing all traces of the client model and files (including the migration). I then ran tests without there being tests, db table, model, or controller for the client. Then I migrated the table back with a different migration using the same table_create method. I then added the files back and tested it. I'm guessing that using a different migration was the solution.